# Use of the definite article

Tags: articles, definite-articles

**Sentence 1:**

> I completely agree with this notion and will make the case for it by
>   analyzing **the** benefits that physical training classes bring to
>   youngsters.

In sentence 1 we must use the definite article because everyone knows which benefits phys-ed classes bring to youngsters, it's just a common sense.

**Sentence 2:**

> Finally, the governmental financial reward for **the** organizations
>   that have incorporated kitchens and gyms into their office spaces
>   would be another effective (sound) countermeasure against the
>   deterioration of public health.

Here we must not use the definite article because there are a lot of such organizations, and it's impossible to say which exactly the author means.

Am I right?

Comment: Please also go through **the** [existing posts about the definite article](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%22definite%20article%22)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do have to use article (the) in the sentence number two too as you are specifying the organizations by using relative pronoun "that". Here you are talking about those organizations which have  incorporated kitchens and gyms
into their office spaces.

Comment: This is correct.  In both cases, you use "the" because you are talking about items from a known, specific set.